# Is exposing the UID a security issue?

Tags: users, security

I noticed that the UID of users is exposed in the HTML code of a page on my site that authenticated users can access.

Is it a problem if authenticated users with "view user profiles" permission are able to find the UID of any non-disabled user account?

Comment: Only if there's an unrelated vulnerability somewhere in your site that would let an attacker make _use_ of that ID in a nefarious fashion. Things have identifiers, there's no getting away from that; it's not something you should spend much time fighting or even worrying about. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is a fun related read :)

Comment: Totally agree with Clive, "Security through obscurity" has nothing to do with security at all. The security from the lock on your door comes from the secret key, not from obfuscating the door handle.

Comment: Third vote to agree with the above two. No risk in and of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post by the Drupal Security Team, it is not considered a vulnerability:

[Disclosure of usernames and user ids is not considered a weakness](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-security-team/security-team-procedures/disclosure-of-usernames-and-user-ids-is-not-considered)

> ### Drupal's philosophy
>
> Usernames are an important part of online identity. Having a public username helps other users of a site to know the identity of the person they are interacting with in a forum or a blog. Drupal is primarily intended to be used for sites where identity and interaction are key elements so it is reasonable for that information to be public.

Of course, it will vary by site, depending on what that information allows other users to see.